# Remove NA by id on stacked paired observations

Tags: r, dplyr, na

I have a df with stacked paired (time 1, time 2) observations (subject = id) of variables (v1,v2)

```
df <- tribble(
  ~id, ~time, ~v1,~ v2,
  1, 1, NA, 7,
  2, 1, 3, 7, 
  3, 1, 2, 6,
  1, 2, 4, 5,
  2, 2, 3, NA,
  3, 2, 7, 6
)
```

For the paired analysis, I need to drop all ids that have NA in either time. In the example above I would be left with only id "3". How can I achieve this? (dplyr if possible.)
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `subset` from `base R`- get the `id` where 'v1' is `NA` (`id[is.na(v1)]`), create a logical with the original 'id' column (`id %in% ..`), negate (`!`) to get the ids having no NAs in 'v1'

```
subset(df, !id %in% id[is.na(v1)])
```

---

Or with `filter` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
filter(df, !id %in% id[is.na(v1)])
# A tibble: 2 × 3
     id  time    v1
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     3     1     2
2     3     2     7
```

---

#### Update

Based on the new data, we can use `if_any`

```
df %>%
   group_by(id) %>% 
   filter(all(!if_any(v1:v2, is.na))) %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 × 4
     id  time    v1    v2
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     3     1     2     6
2     3     2     7     6
```

Or with `if_all`

```
 df %>%
   group_by(id) %>% 
   filter(all(if_all(v1:v2, complete.cases))) %>%
   ungroup
# A tibble: 2 × 4
     id  time    v1    v2
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     3     1     2     6
2     3     2     7     6
```

Comment: Thanks! Actually my inicial example was too simple. I have several variables, like in the edited example above.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(id) %>% filter(!any(is.na(v1+v2))) %>% ungroup

#> # A tibble: 2 × 4
#>      id  time    v1    v2
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     3     1     2     6
#> 2     3     2     7     6
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `complete.cases` and `all` to return only the groups that contain no `NA`s in `v1` or `v2`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(all(complete.cases(v1, v2)))
```

**Output**

```
     id  time    v1    v2
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     3     1     2     6
2     3     2     7     6
```

If you have a lot more columns that start with `v`, then we could use `c_across` to specify the columns in `starts_with`.

```
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(all(complete.cases(c_across(starts_with("v")))))
```